# Styles are not applied when creating buttons Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Styles are not applied when creating buttons. I've tried a lot, but nothing works. I need to make such a screen, but when compiling the buttons are not displayed at all. What can be done?

[image]
[image]

Don't pay attention to the colors, they are temporary)

code for buttons:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_pin_background"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="1"/>
```

file button_pin_background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#4D0CAD" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#753A3F" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

file button_pin_background:

Check if the file is used by other modules or drawable drawable-xx
and other overrides

Comment: it is only used for buttons(